# C11 use of _Atomic with char*

Tags: c, atomic, c11, stdatomic

Using C11 I'm looking to fetch the contents of a `char*` atomically, and was wondering what the best way to go about doing that was. I've defined a variable like so: `_Atomic char* str;`, but attempting to load the value `atomic_load(&str);` results in a compiler error `Address argument to atomic operation must be a pointer to _Atomic type ('_Atomic(char) **' invalid)`

I'm aware that C11's Atomic implementation allows for the declaration of Atomic `char`'s, but how do I go about dealing with malloc'd `char*` pointers?

Comment: Don't you want `char* _Atomic str;` instead? Just like with `const char*` vs `char* const`, it's not the `char` being pointed to that's atomic, but rather the pointer itself.

Comment: Another way to ensure that you have the correct specification would be to use the parenthesized version, `_Atomic(char*)`.

Comment: D'oh! What a silly mistake. Cameron, if you want to write up an answer I'll happily accept it. Thank you.